# KDE method more sensitive to multimodality

Tags: python, scipy, kernel-density, probability-density

I am using scipy's stats.gaussian_kde() to produce a PDF estimate for a sample of data.

Scipy's docs clearly state:

```
"The estimation works best for a unimodal distribution; bimodal or multi-modal distributions tend to be oversmoothed."
```

Is there a method that may be more sensitive to spikes in frequency that does not involve manually setting bandwidth?

My assumption is that, because it is non-parametric, Gaussian KDE does not assume the shape of the distribution-- yet it seems to be forced to assume normality nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/) for an in-depth discussion on KDEs.
The only issue with multimodal distribution, as stated, is over-smoothing, but no normality is assumed, the Gaussian kernel is just a smoothing choice.